# Деплой Go приложения в Docker

Tags: golang, vagrant, docker

Доброго времени суток! Пишу RESTful сервис на Go. Деплой будет происходить в Docker. Поскольку пишу на Windows, то Docker находится на виртуальной машине под управлением Vagrant'a. Всего есть несколько машин с PostgreSQL, nginx и т.д.

Вопрос в следующем - как наиболее удобно и быстро апдейтить приложение в контейнере? Поскольку только начал изучать Gо, то апдейтить придется очень часто и загрязнять историю в гите или использовать Docker Hub не слишком удобно.

Наперед спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Привет.
Тут есть два варианта развития событий.

Первый - это классическая концепция докера, очень тесно перекликающаяся с Immutable Infrastructure. В это концепции контейнер - это законченная, атомарная единица, содержащая в себе сервис, которую, в случае обновления сервиса, необходимо просто выкинуть и заменить новым контейнером с новой версией. Т.е. полностью пересобрать контейнер, и, в этой концепции, это действительно именно то, что нужно. Докер - это не предназначенный для разработки вагрант, а именно способ запаковать приложение.

Есть, конечно, второй вариант, который очень простой, и, в то же время, не совсем docker-way. Докер-контейнеры поддерживают монтирование папки внутрь контейнера (host volume), что позволяет создать полностью подготовленное окружение, внутрь которого с помощью ключа -v прокинуть содержимое из папки хоста, где регулярно компилировать приложение. В случае использования docker-compose подобную штуку можно легко автоматизировать и поднимать буквально одной командой.

P.S.

> загрязнять историю в гите

в этом нет ничего страшного, это нормально.

> RESTfull

RESTful

> находиться

находится